# Can't see scopes, "Waveform, Histogram" no graphs there

Tags: uv-image-editor

I must be doing something wrong, but by no means I´m able to se the scopes “histogram, waveform, etc…” They are blank, clear. Using the 2.8 Beta, any ideas?

[image: All Clear]